# How to add SMS sending function inside a custom module

Tags: magento2, php, php-5.4, php-7

I have to add SMS sending function at the checkout success page.

This is my code:

```
namespace send\sms\Block;

class sendsms extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session
     */
    protected $checkoutSession;

    /**
     * @var int
     */
    protected $oderId;

    /**
     * @var array
     */
    protected $lastOrder;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context
     * @param \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $checkoutSession
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $checkoutSession,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
        $this->checkoutSession = $checkoutSession;
    }

    protected function _prepareLayout()
    {
        $lastOrder = $this->checkoutSession->getLastRealOrder();
        $this->orderId = $lastOrder->getIncrementId();
        $this->lastOrder = $lastOrder->getData();
        return parent::_prepareLayout();
    }

    public function getOrderId()
    {
        return $this->orderId;
    }

    public function getLastOrder()
    {
        return $this->lastOrder;
    }

    public function sendsms()
    {
        $YourAPIKey='<api key>';
        $From="<sender name>";
        $To="<number>";
        $TemplateName="OrderSuccess";
        $VAR1="<var1>";
        $VAR2="<var2>";
        $agent= 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1; .NET CLR 1.0.3705; .NET CLR 1.1.4322)';
        $url = "https://2factor.in/API/V1/$YourAPIKey/ADDON_SERVICES/SEND/TSMS"; 

        $ch = curl_init(); 

        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url); 
        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST,true); 
        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,"TemplateName=$TemplateName&From=$From&To=$To&VAR1=$VAR1&VAR2=$VAR2&VAR3=$VAR3&VAR4=$VAR4&VAR5=$VAR5"); 
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $agent);
        echo curl_exec($ch); 
        curl_close($ch);
        return parent::sendsms();
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate your question ?

Comment: mention correct version of magento , do not mention both 1 & 2

Comment: where you want  add sms end functionality?

Comment: It really depends on the sms provider. Here's an adapter that I've used for Twilio https://github.com/pmclain/module-twilio/blob/master/Model/Adapter/AdapterAbstract.php, but it doesn't look like 2Factor has a php-sdk. If you do wind up making cURL requests, use the Magento abstraction provided by `Magento\Framework\HTTP\ClientFactory`

Comment: @Amit Bera I have to add this function at the checkout success page

Comment: if you want to take reference https://magecomp.com/magento-2-sms-notification.html